# Clustering Wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Do you have any examples of how to cluster docker containers for wso2 api manager and DAS? I currently have a set up where I have separated and running each APIM product profile (manager,worker,store,keymanager and publisher) in separate docker containers. I will be particularly interested in information on how to scale services (for ex. how to add more workers, more stores to the cluster) for high availability and load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

What is the container management system you are using? If its k8s 1 you can refer to below documentations.

Please follow the below documentation which will help you to get an idea on this. In k8s you can achieve the scalability trough increasing the number of pods.

[1] http://kubernetes.io/docs/whatisk8s/

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/KA100/Clustered+Deployment+of+WSO2+Products+on+Kubernetes

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0

[4] https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles/tree/v1.2.0/wso2am